# How to stop loop in while statement in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask.

Is it okay to add **exit();** at the end of each statement or is there any good way besides **exit();** ?

The reason is stop the display data from looping, **Because if I remove/disable exit();**, the data will loop and display all the row available in database table. And else statement will also execute if the exit(); remove from the code.

The code as below :

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $input       = $_POST['input'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $get = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($get && mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 ){ 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
                $input_db  = $row['input'];
                $output_db = $row['output'];

                if (($input >= $input_db) && ($output <= $output_db))
                {
                    echo "Input and output is in between";
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Data added ! <br/>";
                    exit();
                }
            }
        mysqli_free_result($get);   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "data is outside range";
        }
    }
?>
<form action="testdate.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Input : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="input" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You ever used `break` before? http://www.php.net/break

Comment: not really good at it .. that's why i'm using while loop :)

Comment: Can you clarify further? Can it be filtered on SQL level? (e.g WHERE condition)

Comment: @Jamilah "that's why i'm using while loop" doesn't make any sense at all as `break` can also be used in `while loop`.

Comment: why not use `break` it is applicable to all types of loops

Comment: I guess that besides "how" you need to rethink "when" you want to break the loop, because now the logic is flawed: take a bunch of rows, check only the first or respond with "out of range" when table has no data at all - it makes no sense. I think you've changed the code and missed some leftovers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $input = $_POST['input'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $get = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

        $found = false;

        if($get && mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 ){ 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
                $input_db  = $row['input'];
                $output_db = $row['output'];

                if (($input >= $input_db) && ($input <= $output_db))
                {
                    echo "Input and output is in between";
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$found) {
                echo "data is outside range";
            }
            
            mysqli_free_result($get);   
        }
        else {
            echo "No data found";
        }
    }
?>

<form action="testdate.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Input : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="input" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

this code is more optimized it will not load the whole table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Date</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="testdate.php" method="post">  
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
                <td>Input : </td>
                <td><input type ="text" name="input" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

        <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
    </form>

    <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
        global $connect;

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
            $input = $_POST['input'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE input <= ? AND output >= ? LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $input, $input);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result_set = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result_set) > 0) {
                echo "Input and output is in between";
            } else {
                echo "Data is outside range";
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

To directly answer the question, you can simply swap `exit();` with `break;`. That halts a loop without exiting:

```
// Let's go infinite..

while(true)
{

 echo 'This only appears once, because we\'re breaking out of the loop.';

 // Not today!
 break;
}

// Everything is normal again down here.
echo 'That was a close one!';
```

In your specific case, the much better approach is to *only select the data you need*, otherwise MySQL will be busy sending the entire table only for PHP to drop most of the data it's receiving. Something like this:

```
<?php
$connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
global $connect;   

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $input       = (int)$_POST['input']; // * See note below

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table where ".$input.">=`input` and ".$output."<=`output`";

    $get=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    if($get && $get->num_rows)
    {
        echo "Input and output is in between";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "data is outside range";
    }
}
?>
```

- That `(int)` is a simplistic security measure - it prevents someone from performing SQL injections. You'd need to do it to `$output` too. Use prepared queries instead if possible.

Comment: but if i use this technique , how im gonna call the data from database ? i mean let say use while($row = mysqli_fetch_array()) .... $data = $row['data']; .. In your suggestion code how to call the data ?

Comment: If your query does have multiple rows then you could loop them as before - you just wouldn't need to exit as all the result rows are 'relevant' anyway. (Edit: I assumed you only needed one row as your existing code can only ever handle one anyway).

Comment: You'd need to at least define $output (it wasn't defined in the original source either). Direct question answer: just use break instead. Specific answer: Probably need to see more code, but your question is too specific about while loops.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Code won't work because `mysqli_query` method returns `bool` that tells if query was executed. You need to get result (one fetch) to determine if there was a data-wise success. Also no need to grab all columns from matched row and since one result is sufficient the `LIMIT 1` is also a good idea. `SELECT 1 FROM...WHERE...LIMIT 1`

Comment: @shudder Nope: It returns null here (when it fails) and an object when it doesn't; it's a select statement (PHP evaluates null to false).

Comment: @LukeBriggs Right. But still mysqli_result object might be empty

Comment: @shudder Ah whoops I see what you're saying now; updated. (The OP code appears to be condensed anyway so I was trying to be a little too concise there).

Comment: @Jamilah can you not filter your SQL query with "WHERE"?